# Example code for Bilinear Interpolation

Tags: c#, image-processing

I'm playing with images and I was wondering if anyone has a link to an open source image processing library that utilizes bilinear and bicubic interpolation for scaling and rotating images. I'm trying to learn the math behind it, so even a pretty good walk through of how these kinds of interpolations can be coded up would be excellent.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

GDI+, aka System.Drawing.Imaging, does all of this.  You do not need a 3rd party DLL.  See the Graphics class.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that GDI+ does all that.  But I'm more interested in "How" it does it than actually doing it.

Comment: this is only 1/2 right too... there are a few things you can do with direct bilinear interpolation that you can't do with GDI+ and System.Drawing directly... specifically warping an image in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

A great library is the AForge image processing library.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I should be more clear huh?  I'll take a look at that library :)